# how to access a variable inside the function from another class

Tags: php

how do i access variables inside function that are in the class from another class.

in the below ex .. I wanted to access $asdf in another class.

for example

```
class abc{
    public function foo1(){
        $asdf ='YEAHHHHH';
  }
}
class xyz{
    private qw;
    public function foo2(){
        $this->qw= new foo1();
        $this->qw->foo1()->asdf; // asdf is not found..
        echo $this->qw
    }
}
```

Comment: Have your function return the value.

Comment: `$this->qw->foo1()->asdf;` goes against almost all the rules or scope, syntax and variably visibility.

Comment: not possible. `$asdf` is a local variable and would exist only while  the `foo1()` method is actually executing. doing `$this->asdf = 'yeah'` would work, but even then the variable would exist only after foo1's been called at least once.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the function returns the value as needed, ie:

```
return $asdf;
```

You can then reference and assign the value to a variable:

```
$value = $this->qw->foo1();
```

So your code would look something like this:

```
class abc{
    public function foo1(){
        $asdf ='YEAHHHHH';
        return $asdf;
    }
}
class xyz{
    private qw;
    public function foo2(){
        $this->qw= new foo1();
        $value = $this->qw->foo1(); 
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create `object` of `class` to access the `class` property and use `return` in `foo1()`. Example here..

```
class abc{
    public function foo1(){
        return 'YEAHHHHH';
    }
}

class xyz{
    private $qw;
    public function foo2(){
        $obj = new abc();
        echo $this->qw = $obj->foo1();
    }
}

$obj = new xyz();
$obj->foo2();

Output: YEAHHHHH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class abc{
    public function foo1(){
        $asdf ='YEAHHHHH';
        return $asdf;
    }
}
class xyz{
    private qw = new abc();
    public function foo2(){
        echo $this->qw->foo1();
    }
}
```

1. Have your first function return something
2. Create an instance of the required class inside the other class (you should look into extended)
3. Call the necessary function
4. Echo the returned data from the called function